# Rails ActiveRecord associations inconsistently updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I am running into some Rails 2.3.5 ActiveRecord behavior I do not understand. It appears that an object can have its association ids updated in inconsistent ways.

This is best explained with an example:

Create a `Post` model with the string attribute `'title'` and a `Comment` model with the string attribute `'content'`.

Here are the associations:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Scenario #1: In the following code I create one `Post` with an associated `Comment`, create a second `Post` by `find`'ing the first, add a second `Comment` to the first `Post` and discover that the second `Post` has the second `Comment` associated to it without an explicit assignment.

```
post1 = Post.new
post1 = Post.new(:title => 'Post 1')
comment1 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 1')
post1.comments << comment1
post1.save
# Create a second Post object by find'ing the first
post2 = Post.find_by_title('Post 1')
# Add a new Comment to the first Post object
comment2 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 2')
post1.comments << comment2 
# Note that both Comments are associated with both Post objects even
# though I never explicitly associated it with post2.
post1.comment_ids # => [12, 13]
post2.comment_ids # => [12, 13]
```

Scenario #2: Run the above commands again but this time insert one extra command that, on the face of it, should not affect the results. The extra command is `post2.comments` which occurs *after* creating `comment2` and *before* adding `comment2` to `post1`.

```
post1 = Post.new
post1 = Post.new(:title => 'Post 1A')
comment1 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 1A')
post1.comments << comment1
post1.save
# Create a second Post object by find'ing the first
post2 = Post.find_by_title('Post 1A')
# Add a new Comment to the first Post object
comment2 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 2A')
post2.comments # !! THIS IS THE EXTRA COMMAND !!
post1.comments << comment2 
# Note that both Comments are associated with both Post objects even
# though I never explicitly associated it with post2.
post1.comment_ids # => [14, 15]
post2.comment_ids # => [14]
```

Note that there is only **one** comment associated with `post2` in this scenario whereas in Scenario 1 there were two.

The Big Question: Why would running `post2.comments` before adding the new `Comment` to `post1` make any difference to which Comments were associated with `post2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way that Active Record caches requests and the way that has_many associations are handled.

Unless the association is eagerloaded with an :include option during the find. Rails will not populate the association for the found records until needed. When the association is needed some [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is done to cut down on the number of SQL queries executed.

Stepping through the code in the question:

```
post1 = Post.new(:title => 'Post 1')
comment1 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 1')
post1.comments << comment1  # updates post1's internal comments cache
post1.save 

# Create a second Post object by find'ing the first
post2 = Post.find_by_title('Post 1') 

# Add a new Comment to the first Post object
comment2 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 2')
post1.comments << comment2   # updates post1's internal comments cache

# Note that both Comments are associated with both Post objects even
# though I never explicitly associated it with post2.
post1.comment_ids # => [12, 13]

# this is the first time post2.comments are loaded. 
# SELECT comments.* FROM comments JOIN comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.id = #{post2.id}
post2.comment_ids # => [12, 13]
```

Scenario 2:

```
post1 = Post.new(:title => 'Post 1A')
comment1 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 1A')
post1.comments << comment1
post1.save

# Create a second Post object by find'ing the first
post2 = Post.find_by_title('Post 1A')

# Add a new Comment to the first Post object
comment2 = Comment.new(:content => 'content 2A')

# first time post2.comments are loaded. 
# SELECT comments.* FROM comments JOIN comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE 
#   posts.id = post2.comments #=> Returns one comment (id = 14)
# cached internally.

post1.comments << comment2 
# Note that both Comments are associated with both Post objects even
# though I never explicitly associated it with post2.
post1.comment_ids # => [14, 15]

# post2.comment has already been cached, so the SQL query is not executed again.

post2.comment_ids # => [14]
```

N.B. `post2.comment_ids` is internally defined as `post2.comments.map(&:id)`

P.S. My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252743/calling-activerecords-relationship-ids-1-2-3-saves-immediately-any-workaro/2254992#2254992) might help you understand why post2 gets updated despite your not touching it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesn't this behavior seem wrong? Caching should improve performance, not cause result inconsistency.

Comment: It's more a concurrency issue. Rails doesn't expect an outside source to change things related to an instance of a model. Outside source in this case meaning any actions that originating from some where other than the specific instance. If strongly believe this is wrong, file a bug report.